# Are there references to generally known public knowledge under U.S. law?

Tags: united-states, civil-law

Under some European jurisdictions, the concept of information known by the broad public hence it requires no proof before the court exist and is accepted to be true unless proven otherwise.

Does a similar concept exist under U.S. law?

Can you make an averment based on generally known public knowledge?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called "judicial notice." In federal court, it's covered by [Rule 201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_201) of the Federal Rules of Evidence:

> (b) Kinds of Facts That May Be Judicially Noticed. The court may judicially notice a fact that is not subject to reasonable dispute because it:
>
> (1) is generally known within the trial court’s territorial jurisdiction; or
>
> (2) can be accurately and readily determined from sources whose accuracy cannot reasonably be questioned.

> (c) Taking Notice. The court:
>
> (1) may take judicial notice on its own; or
>
> (2) must take judicial notice if a party requests it and the court is supplied with the necessary information.

States mostly have similar rules for state courts.

Comment: "Can you make an averment based on generally known public knowledge?" Also yes.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you! Really appreciate it!